# How to render images/ videos like instagram that can not be saved when you use browser save page as options

Tags: javascript, html, image, video, frontend

Does anyone know why instagram images are not being saved when you save web page? Just trying to understand technology as looking to implement same in on of my application

Comment: Do you have a testable link of some Instagram page to see what you mean?

Comment: Basically, you go to any Instagram page, though images are served with img tag itself, if you select File -> Save Page as option of browser, you will see that you will see all of the code files but images won't get saved. Which is surprising. As generally Save Page as option saves all of the HTML, JS, Images served in a web page